# Is there a way to make VS Code stop highlighting C++ errors without disabling the extension?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino

Please, help me.

I need VSCode to stop highlight (underline) errors in C++ (.ino files).
I am trying to code a firmware for Arduino board but its highlighting, for example `pinMode()` as error (not defined) even if  both Arduino and Arduino snippets extensions are installed and enabled.

I already tried to set `problems.decoration.enabled` to `false`, but it did not fix my problem. I can't uninstall or disable C/C++ extension because that is what Arduino extension depends on.

Can someone please help me fix this? Thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, it specifically relates to Arduino and VSCode intellisense incorrectly flagging some code. See open github issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino/issues/1556

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Files -> Preferences -> Settings -> Here you can disable the relevent IntelliSense suggestions.

You can also edit the Workspace settings and change the C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine setting from "Default" to "Tag Parser"